# Is there any yii2-like debug in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, yii2

I have troubles with debugging API calls. When I load page, it tries to get some data from API and returns 500 internal server error. But there is no info about it in chrome console unlike when you just open page with fatal error.

Of course I can open api page itself in browser and it could throw same fatal error as any other page, but this page requires authorization via middleware, and one of them, RedirectIfAuthenticated redirects it to home. When I removed redirect it redirects to login page and so on. Mostly I cannot be sure that this error related to page I'm debugging and not a result of removing middleware etc.

So this makes API debugging hard and I thought if there was debugger like in Yii2, where on specific page all last requests listed with links to personal error pages with full error log. Only thing I was able to find is debugbar component, which, unlike in Yii2, does not show results of ajax requests on page.

Comment: I am also using debugbar and it does show results of ajax requests.

Answer (score 1):

For laravel i recommend to use [laravel debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) Its not an exact match for Yii debug but we can get the most out of it.

Comment: that's debugbar I found and I cannot find where ajax call results logged. I see 500 ISE in chrome console, but nothing in debugbar itself